# Change main site in multisite install?

Tags: multisite

I'm redesigning/redeveloping a client's website. Their current site lives on a WordPress network with 2 other sites living on subdomains. It's currently set up as:

- `domain.com` (the site being redesigned)
- `one.domain.com` (which won't be touched)
- `two.domain.com` (also won't be touched)

What I'd like to do is make a `staging.domain.com` site on the same network install that the redesign will live at.

My question is, once the site is ready to launch how do I switch the network's "main" site to `staging.domain.com`, having it live at `domain.com`, and change what's currently at `domain.com` to something like `old.domain.com`?

Comment: Why don't you design offline on your local test install. Once done, simply put the site in maintenance mode (*at a convenient time*) for a few minutes while you upload your changes. This will save on redirects, 404's and probably loss in SEO ratings

Comment: Simply put, it's not just a redesign. We're reveloping it and populating new content. I'll need a new set of database tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Having the naked domain as your first site of a multisite is the ideal and you should work to keep it that way. The good news is that if you've already got multisite setup, you can theoretically make as many subdomains as you like. There are also various plugins out there that can clone sites within multisite for you. Why not clone your main site to the staging. subdomain as you suggested, then clone it again to old.sudomain when you've finished your coding, and then clone staging back to the naked domain? You could also export the database for each and do a manual search and replace in your IDE.